# YII2: Add multiple field in form via two saprate models

Tags: yii2, formfield

Create a multiple field form in YII2.

For example:
I have 2 fields like username and number username store in one table while number store in other table.  And user can add multiple number while click on add more. So how can we do that with yii2, with validation?

Comment: do you need to use yii validation with models ? Also please tell the names of both your models related to both tables

Comment: I have a similar problem. If you read the description of my problem, you will probably find the answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130867/yii2-adding-dynamic-datecontrol-fields-from-related-model-to-a-form